# Ruby failed to create app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby, i want to set up a new hello application in ruby, but i get always this error: (i am using osx, mountain lion), what to do?

rails new hello
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: rack(1.5.2 not ~> 1.4.5) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in`activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in`each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in`activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in`activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your gems:

```
sudo gem update
```

However, you will also be a lot happier if you also update your ruby. There are various ways to do this, but I am particularly fond of `rbenv`, which you can find at github. If you install `rbenv` and also its plug-in `ruby-build`, you can ask `rbenv` to download and install a higher version of ruby in a single command. Note that you will need to have installed Xcode first, including the Xcode command-line tools.

In fact, I just tried this and it worked. I used `rbenv` and `ruby-build` to install Ruby 2.0 freshly on Mountain Lion, as described here:

http://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/ruby2onmountainlion.html

I switched rbenv to use ruby 2.0. That didn't include `rails`, though, so I then did `gem install rails`. Finally, I said: `.rbenv/shims/rails new hello` and it worked. (The only reason I had to specify the path like that is that I'd forgotten, in all the excitement, to do an `rbenv rehash`. Silly me.)

So this must work, because I just did it in real time, between the time you asked your question and the time I wrote this answer!

Comment: my other question is that how to create an xcode project for a ruby on rails webapplication?

Comment: I followed all this instructions : http://createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-with-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/ 

but... :S Same issue

Comment: No, because if you really followed those instructions you would be using Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your version of rack isn't supported with the version of ruby you are using. It also looks like you are using ruby 1.8, which is pretty outdated. I would try and go back and use 1.9.3, or ruby 2.0, which might solve your problem. Also, as far as text editors go, I would go with Sublime Text... http://www.sublimetext.com/2 It has a lot more shortcuts than TextMate.